# SSH rate limiting using Puppet firewall module

Tags: ruby, iptables, puppet

I used to do simple SSH rate limiting using an [UFW Puppet module](https://forge.puppet.com/attachmentgenie/ufw). To get more flexible blocking I've changed to using the [official firewall module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/firewall) instead. Are there any significant issues with the following?

In [manifests/host.pp](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/f208f7f721902e71c6c13775a5b524bba081ba90/manifests/host.pp#L96-L103):

```
include ssh_server
include my_firewall
[…]
resources { 'firewall':
  purge => true,
}

Firewall {
  before  => Class['my_firewall::post'],
  require => Class['my_firewall::pre'],
}
```

In [modules/my_firewall/manifests/init.pp](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/f208f7f721902e71c6c13775a5b524bba081ba90/modules/my_firewall/manifests/init.pp):

```
class my_firewall {
  include my_firewall::pre
  include my_firewall::post

  package { 'ufw':
    ensure => absent,
  }
}
```

In [modules/my_firewall/manifests/pre.pp](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/f208f7f721902e71c6c13775a5b524bba081ba90/modules/my_firewall/manifests/pre.pp):

```
class my_firewall::pre {
  Firewall {
    require => undef,
  }
  # Default firewall rules
  firewall { '000 accept all icmp':
    proto  => 'icmp',
    action => 'accept',
  } ->
  firewall { '001 accept all to lo interface':
    proto   => all,
    iniface => lo,
    action  => accept,
  } ->
  firewall { '002 reject local traffic not on loopback interface':
    iniface     => '! lo',
    proto       => all,
    destination => '127.0.0.1/8',
    action      => reject,
  } ->
  firewall { '003 accept related established rules':
    proto  => all,
    state  => ['RELATED', 'ESTABLISHED'],
    action => accept,
  }
}
```

In [modules/my_firewall/manifests/post.pp](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/f208f7f721902e71c6c13775a5b524bba081ba90/modules/my_firewall/manifests/post.pp):

```
class my_firewall::post {
  firewall { '999 drop all':
    proto  => 'all',
    action => 'drop',
    before => undef,
  }
}
```

In [modules/ssh_server/manifests/init.pp](https://github.com/l0b0/root/blob/f208f7f721902e71c6c13775a5b524bba081ba90/modules/ssh_server/manifests/init.pp#L17-L34):

```
firewall { '200 limit incoming SSH connections to 6 per minute':
  dport     => 22,
  proto     => tcp,
  recent    => update,
  rseconds  => 60,
  rhitcount => 6,
  rname     => 'SSH',
  rsource   => true,
  action    => drop,
} ->
firewall { '201 allow incoming SSH connections':
  dport   => 22,
  proto   => tcp,
  recent  => set,
  rname   => 'SSH',
  rsource => true,
  action  => accept,
}
```